# The file couldn’t be opened using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)

Tags: swift, string, url, unicode, utf-8

I'm trying to see if I can connect to https://www.google.com with:

```
do {
    let s = try String(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!, encoding: .utf8)
    print(s)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The error I receive is:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The file couldn’t be opened
>   using text encoding Unicode (UTF-8)."
>   UserInfo={NSURL=https://www.google.com/, NSStringEncoding=4}

Viewing the page info on https://www.google.com states that it is using UTF-8:

[image]

Why is it always throwing an error?

Comment: You need to use `.ascii`

Comment: @LeoDabus that works. Could you supply an answer with the reasoning? Its unclear to me why I'm not able to use UTF-8.